# Convert MYSQL query to Laravel syntax

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to remake a request under Laravel?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `mines-game` WHERE `id_users` = '$this->user->id' 
   AND `onOff` = '1' 
 ORDER 
    BY `id` DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is an English language site so both titles and content need to be in English. As an aside, including arithmetic operators in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: **DO NOT** use SQL injection. Use [placeholder values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries).

Answer (score 0):

```php
DB::table('mines-games')
   ->select('*')
   ->where(['id_users'=>$this->user->id,'onOff'=>1])
   ->orderByDesc('id')
   ->limit(1)
   ->get();
```

> Make sure you import the `DB` class

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` on top of your file, or use it's full path instead

---

the `->get()` will return an array, so you need to consider that it's not a single object, you need to foreach that, or however you prefer. you can use `->first()` instead of `->get()` and remove the `->limit(1)` if you choose to use `first()`